# Equivalence of magnetic Sobolev norms and usual Sobolev norms

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I know (and it is straightforward to show) that the magnetic Sobolev norm

$$\|f\|_{H^2_A(\mathbb{R}^n)} := \sqrt{ \|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2 + \|(-i\nabla +A)^2f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2} $$

(works also for $H^1_A(\mathbb{R}^n)$) is equivalent to the usual $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ($H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ respectively) norm *if* $A$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e $A\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $A\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. My question is: Are there weaker conditions for $A$ other than being bounded (and continuously differentiable) such that the statement still holds?

To add detail why it is true for $A$ being bounded: You basically use the following fact: Let $A\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Then for all $f\in H^2_A(\mathbb{R}^3)$ 
$$\|f\|_{H^2_A(\mathbb{R}^3)} = \|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} + \|(-i\nabla+A)^2f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} + \|\Delta f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} + \|2(A\cdot \nabla)f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} + \|A^2f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} \leq C_1\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} +C_2\|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} +\|\Delta f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$

which leads to the claim. This strategy obviously works if and only if $A$ is bounded. But is there maybe any other way to go without assuming that $A$ is bounded?

Comment: $\|(-i\nabla +A)^2\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ confuses me, since $(-i\nabla +A)^2$ does not seem like a $L^2$ function. And i guess you want to use the multiplication operator corresponding to $A$.

Comment: There seems to be something missing. The second summand does not depend on $f$.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Sorry, that's sloppy editing from my side. You're right, it should be $\|(-i\nabla +A)^2f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$.

Comment: Reference for $H^1_A$: Lieb-Loss, *Analysis*, 2nd edition, §7.20.

Comment: Isn't A an operator? This has different implications than $A \in L^\infty$, bounded operators are defined differently and continuity of an operator is just equivalent to boundedness. In this case, can you prove equivalent norms if we just assume that $A$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: @djkat $A$ is a function and by abuse of notation, $A$ as an operator is just the multiplication operator on $L^2$ corresponding to the function $A$.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @djkat You're welcome! But could you elaborate on your statement about self-adjointness? Is it true (or obvious) that for self-adjoint $A$ there is equivalence?

Comment: I self-adjointedness is a slightly less structured assumption than boundedness for operators so it was just a guess.